# How to correctly update embedded object's field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How do i correctly update the `resetPasswordExpires` field in mongodb document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("000"), 
    "username" : "root", 
    "isActive" : "yes", 
    "email" : "email@gmail.com", 
    "roles" : { 
        "admin" : ObjectId("111") 
    }, 
    "resetPasswordExpires" : ISODate("2015-06-19T18:04:40.014Z"),
    "resetPasswordToken" : "token" 
}
```

I tried:

```
db.users.update(
    { item: "000" },
    {
      $set: {  "roles.resetPasswordExpires":  ISODate("2015-06-20T18:04:40.014Z")}
})
```

and

```
db.users.update(
    { item: "111" },
    {
      $set: {  "roles.resetPasswordExpires":  ISODate("2015-06-20T18:04:40.014Z")}
})
```

and a few other variations without matching.

Comment: Try `$set: {  "resetPasswordExpires":  ISODate("2015-06-20T18:04:40.014Z")}`, the `resetPasswordExpires` field is a top-level property and not part of the roles subdocument as you had previously attempted.

Comment: cheers. shoulda seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query needs to match on the `_id` (at least that is what it appears you are trying to match on). The update value for `resetPasswordExpires` is not a property of `roles`. Something like the following should work:

```
db.users.update(
  { _id: ObjectId("000") },
  {$set: {  "resetPasswordExpires":  ISODate("2015-06-20T18:04:40.014Z")}
});
```